# Weak scaling of mpi program for matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: mpi, linear-algebra, hpc

I have written some mpi code that solves systems of equations using the conjugate gradient method. In this method matrix-vector multiplication takes up most of the time. As a parallelization strategy, I do the multiplication in blocks of rows and then I
gather the results in the root process. The remaining steps are performed by the root process which broadcasts the results whenever a matrix-vector multiplication needs to be performed.

The strong scaling curve representing the speedup is fine

[image]

But the weak scaling curve representing the efficiency is quite bad

[image]

In theory, the blue curve should be close to the red one.

Is this intrinsic to the parallelization strategy or am I doing something wrong?

**Details**

The measurements are in seconds. The experiments are performed on a cluster where each node has
2 Skylake processors running at 2.3 GHz, with 18 cores each,192 GB of DDR3 RAM and 800GB NVMe local drive. Amdahl's prediction is computed with the formula (0.0163 + 0.9837 / p)^-1. Gustafson's prediction is computed with the formula 0.9873+0.0163/p where p is the number of processors. The experimental values are in both cases obtained by dividing the time spent by a single computation unit by the time spent by p computation units.

For weak scaling, I start with a load per processor of W = 1768^2 matrix entries. Then the load with p processors will be M^2 = pW matrix cells. Thus, we set the matrix's side to M = 1768 \sqrt{p} for p processes. This gives: 1768, 3536, 5000, 7071 and 10000 cells for 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 processors respectively. I also fix the number of iterations to 500 so that the measurements are not affected by the variability in the data.

Comment: If you want a scalable algorithm, you should not do any gathers and broadcasts. Create all your data distributed, and keep it distributed. Since strong scaling is usually harder to achieve than weak scaling, my guess is that your have an error in your scalability computation.

Comment: Details are missing to answer this question: how the red and blue curves are *precisely* computed? That is, what is the code for the blue curve and what expression did you specifically use for the red. The hardware also matters starting from the HPC interconnect. Additionally, we have no idea of the timings: is it 1 second, 1 ms, 1 us ? Latencies can make things more complex than most theoretical prediction can do. Put it shortly, we need the parameters to *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I'm mostly interested in understanding why this algorithm does not scale. I have added information on how I computed scalability.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have added some information.

Comment: @harold There is a difference between scaling and performing. Matrix-vector should be a perfectly scaling, low performing algorithm. Footnote 1: at least if you have multiple nodes, and you use the right distribution. Footnote 2: you'd be surprised how much bandwidth a high-core-count node has these days. Have you actually tested your bandwdith argument? IIRC getting perfect scaling with 3/4 of the cores should be easily attainable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Amdahl formula is wrong. It should be:

```
S_p = F_s + p F_p
```

You have a division that should be a multiplication. See for instance [https://theartofhpc.com/istc/parallel.html#Gustafson'slaw](https://theartofhpc.com/istc/parallel.html#Gustafson%27slaw)

Comment: Isn't that the formula for the speedup? What was plotted in the graph was the efficiency which is the speedup divided by p. I'll clarify this in the graphs

Comment: Oh I see, you have one speed up and one efficiency curve. Can you make them both speedup or both efficiency? This is confusing.